# Magento use SSL/https for certain IP only

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, ssl, development, https

I need to put a check on IP. I want to use SSL/https only for my IP.

<del>Where is the method that forms baseUrl with https or http?</del>
Where can I do this?

Comment: not method is available at magento  which set  set https only for one IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole config is being loaded pretty early on in the app run and there are no events being dispatched related to this. I think the best way you could do this, is by hooking into the earliest event being dispatched, which would be `controller_front_init_before` ([according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410410/whats-the-earliest-event-magento-dispatches)).

So you would need to write an event observer and in this observer you could manually set the config for secure/SSL.

You'll need to configure a valid secure base URL and set `use_in_frontend` to "No" (= `0`). Then in this observer you can change this on the fly for certain IP addresses:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '123.123.123.123') {
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('web/secure/use_in_frontend', '1');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the secure url in admin panel.

> Admin > System > Configuration > Web > Secure Url

Give Secure Url in the respected fields and enable SSL for frontend.

Comment: I now this. But I want to set https only for my IP